# search customers in front end by billing data

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search

i have got this code , but i can´t search by billing_phone

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>">
    <div class="user-form">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form> .author-search -->

<?php
if( $_GET['s'] ) {

    $search_term = sanitize_text_field( stripslashes( $_GET['s']));


// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'role'       => 'Customer',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'display_name',
    'search' => '*' . esc_attr( $search_term ) . '*',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'nickname',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'billing_phone',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// Get the results
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();

// Check for results
if ( ! empty( $authors ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    // loop through each author
    foreach ( $authors as $author ) {
        // get all the user's data
        $author_info = get_userdata( $author->ID );
        echo '<li>' . $author_info->nickname . ' ' . $author_info->last_name . '</li>';
                echo '<li>' . $author_info->billing_phone . '</li><br>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
} 

else {
    echo 'No authors found';
}

}
?>
```

how do this??

Comment: Why are you adding `*` to the search term?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two issues that can be resolved in one go:

```php
'search' => '*' . esc_attr( $search_term ) . '*',
```

- You don't need the `'*'`s around the term. It looks like you're trying to do a wildcard, but that's what search already does by adding SQL '%' around your term. Essentially, you end up searching for `"%*{$search_term}*%"`, which is probably not what you want.
- `esc_attr` should be unnecessary here. The WordPress database class used in your query will escape your input for you.
- Using `search` in this context is creating a query like this:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM wp_users JOIN wp_usermeta ... WHERE (
 (
   meta_key = 'nickname' AND meta_value LIKE 'search term'
 ) OR 
 (
   meta_key LIKE 'last_name'
 ...
 )
AND
 (
   wp_users.ID LIKE 'search term'
  OR
   wp_users.user_login LIKE 'search term'
 )
) -- END WHERE
```

which is also probably not what you want. In a `WP_User_Query`, `search` means "Search for user logins matching this query", not "search for general user meta matching this query."

So, try something like this:

```php
    // wp_user_query arguments
    $args = array (
        'role'       => 'customer',
        'order'      => 'asc',
        'orderby'    => 'display_name',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'or',
            array(
                'key'     => 'nickname',
                'value'   => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'like'
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'last_name',
                'value'   => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'like'
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'billing_phone',
                'value'   => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'like'
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: I am very grateful, it works correctly but I can not give you a public score for not having 15 points on my profile.

I would like the link to appear in the result so that the customer profile can be edited    if ( ! empty( $authors ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    // loop through each author
    foreach ( $authors as $author ) {
        // get all the user's data
        $author_info = get_userdata( $author->ID );
        echo '<li>' . $author_info->nickname . ' ' . $author_info->last_name . '</li>';
                echo '<li>' . $author_info->billing_phone . '</li><br>';

    }

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer by clicking the "check" mark. Also, your loop code looks ok to me, but as a note you'll get `WP_User` objects back from your query, so calling `get_userdata` may be overkill.